# ng-options with filter not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, ng-options

I have a select in my HTML like this (moreCourses is the name of my controller):

```
<select class="form-control" ng-options="course.courseId as course.courseName for course in moreCourses.coursesToshow track by course.courseId | filter: {show: true}" ng-model="course.newcourse" data-ng-change="moreCourses.showCourse(course)">
    <option style="display:none" value="">Choose a course</option>
</select>
```

And this is the array with the objects for the select:

```
var coursesToshow =
        [{
            courseName: 'English for Work',
            courseId: 'en-efw',
            show: true
        },
        {
            courseName: 'Practice Courses',
            courseId: 'en-practice',
            show: true
        },
        {
            courseName: 'English for Doctors',
            courseId: 'en-efd',
            show: true
        }];
```

Everything works fine, but the filter it isn't work, and the value for the property ´show´ change to ´false´ when the user select an option, I've checked that.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to first apply the filter and then add the trackBy expression. `course.courseId as course.courseName for course in moreCourses.coursesToshow | filter: {show: true} track by course.courseId`. See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: Could you include the `newCourse` model and `showCourse` method

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Numyx, the solution is the order for the `select`, it should be `track by` after `filter`

```
<select class="form-control" ng-options="course.courseId as course.courseName for course in moreCourses.coursesToshow | filter: {show: true} track by course.courseId" ng-model="course.newcourse" data-ng-change="moreCourses.showCourse(course)">
    <option style="display:none" value="">Choose a course</option>
```